# How do I solve this? "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null"

Tags: javascript

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <script>  
      var paragraph = document.createElement("p");    
      var text = document.createTextNode("Boom it is me");    
      paragraph.appendChild(text);
      var element = document.getElementById('text')

     element.appendChild(text);
     </script>        
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    #text{
        color: green;
    }
    </style>
    <p>Some text</p>
    <div id="text">
    <p>Some text2</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

`what's the problem of this? Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property.`

Comment: Can you post your code correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the elements to DOM before appending any child elements to them.

Before

`paragraph.appendChild(text);`

add this line

`document.body.appendChild(paragraph);`

Also, You need to do these operations when the document object is available for DOM operations (after document is ready, or after window onload)

```
window.onload = function(){
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
  var text = document.createTextNode("Boom it is me");
  paragraph.appendChild(text);
  var element = document.getElementById('text')
  element.appendChild(text);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null”

This is because `var element = document.getElementById('text')` is inside `head` tag but `text` is not at all present in DOM when this line is parsed

So you can either put the entire script near closing tag of `body`

```
<body>
 // DOM elements

<script>
// your code
</script>
</body>
```

or

put it inside `window.onload`